# ASP.Net form tag within form tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I am running into this issue, I need to insert a form tag inside a form tag. My master page has my HTML code which contains form tags, within that I have a ContentPlaceHolder: 
This is my HTML page:

```
<html>
  <header>
    //my code here.
  </header>

  <body>
    <form>
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
  </body>
<html>
```

now I want to do something like this in my page.aspx:
page.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server" defaultfocus="Submit">

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       //my code here  
    </div>
    </form>

</asp:Content>
```

Error I am getting:
A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

After doing a lot of reading and research, I figured out it is not possible, but I have not read what would be a solution, please advise a way/ways to do solve this problem. Thank you for reading my question.

This is my code now in page.aspx, but my postback is not working:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server" defaultfocus="Submit">

        <div>
        <span style ="font-family:Arial">Select Country : </span> 
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" Enabled = "true" AutoPostBack = "true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text = "--Select Country--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br /><br />        
    </div> 
</asp:Content>
```

SAM,
I added this to the page.aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Enabled = "true" AutoPostBack = "true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text = "--Select Country--" Value = "0"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text = "Sri Lanka" Value = "1"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

and in my c# file, I have:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "you selected Sri Lanka";
}
```

when I select Sri Lanka, nothing happens.

Comment: Can I ask why you *need* to insert a form tag within your Page as well as in your Master Page ? Is it just to act as a container, or is there some other reason ?

Comment: it is just a container.

Comment: If you need to use Forms per each page just don't use Masterpages and ContentPages. Just use Web Forms (This is available when you add items to your project)

Comment: I did the following, I removed the form tags and just used my code without form. looks like it works except that my postback is not working? Do you happen to know why? Thank you!

Comment: It should work. Update the question with some of your controls and the code behind code

Comment: The drop down, when I click it and select a country, it should says I selected this country. Now what I have to do is, I click the dropdown, select the country, refresh then I can see: I selected this country, which is a label text.

Comment: Add one more item to your DropDown and see what happens :-D

Comment: See the update to my answer below

Comment: It should work. What's in your <%@ Page tag?

Comment: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" EnableEventValidation="false"  %>

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a server side `form` within another server side `form`. You should inherit your page from `MasterPage` and then use a `ContentPlaceHolder` to hold your page specific controls.

E.g. Your page.aspx should look like something like this

```
<%@ Page Title="My Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MySite.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test._Page" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="MyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MyContent">
    <%-- Your controls --%>
</asp:Content>
```

If you need to do partial updates use an `UpdatePanel`

**UPDATE**

You must add more than 1 item to trigger the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of a DropDownList control

E.g.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" Enabled = "true" AutoPostBack = "true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text = "--Select Country--" Value = "0"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text = "Sri Lanka" Value = "1"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```